# How to set minDate/maxDate from array in jQuery ui datepicker widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a html `table` where each row contains a datepicker field. In each row in a separate `td`, I have a input field with a class of `product_id`. Lastly there is an array of objects with these product ids as its keys, and looks something like:

```
dateDetails[2].start_date = '2014-08-10' //year-month-day
dateDetails[2].end_date = '2014-10-10'
dateDetails[5].start_date = '2014-08-14'
dateDetails[5].end_date = '2014-12-16'
```

The code I am trying is:

```
$(".txt_DatePicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        //Logs the expected date
        console.log(dateDetails[$(this).closest('tr').find('.product_id').val()].start_date);
        .......
        ...
    },
    minDate: new Date(dateDetails[$(this).closest('tr').find('.product_id').val()].start_date),//Throws undefined error
    maxDate: new Date(dateDetails[$(this).closest('tr').find('.product_id').val()].end_date),
    dateFormat: "dd MM, yy"
});
```

As you can see, the code shows the value within the `beforeShowDay` but throws an `Undefined` error, during the `minDate\maxDate`lines. I am guessing this happens because at that point the datepicker hasn't been initialized so it cannot find `$(this)`. But this is only my guess, and I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',minDate:'2013-09-10' ,maxDate:'2013-10-10'});
```

Comment: Did you read the question? I cannot hardcode the dates. They need to be fetched dynamically from the array during initialization